# amp: sqrt() square root into amp-animation

Tags: javascript, css, amp-html

amp-animation supports `calc()` but I need to calculate the square root cause I need to use the diagonal of the viewport as parameter for a transform scale.
as far as I understand `calc()` into amp-animation works exactly as `calc()` into CSS so it doesn't support square root.

anyone has an idea about how to calculate the square root into amp-animation or about how to pass the `viewport` diagonal to amp-animation?

Comment: You may have to pre-determine the target values and link to the target media query.